# Preserving newlines and carriage returns from a selection using range? javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, range, getselection

I have the following code

```
if(this.window.getSelection) {
  var range = this.range;
  var contents = range.extractContents();
  console.log(contents);
  return contents.textContent;
}
```

contents gives me a document fragment.  When I check the text content of that fragment it collapses the newlines in my selection into a single string.

How do I preserve the formatting of the string?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `contents.innerHTML` if your `contents` is a html element, or `contents.html()` if it is a jQuery object.

ps: is `this.window.getSelection` not supposed to be `this.window.getSelection()`?

Comment: contents.innerHTML isnt defined :(

Comment: is 'contents' a html element or a jQuery object?

Comment: its a string of text in a wsiwyg iframe dealy..  i see each newline of text in the childnodes part of the documentfragment...

Comment: if it is really a string of text, it should show as a string of (uncollapsed) text. Otherwise it is probably an object, and my guess is a jQuery object with children, so you can try 'contents.children().html()'